# Way of simplifying binary multiplication

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, binary

Is there a way to simplify multiplication of binary numbers regardless of digits? Or do we always have to resort to 10-base multiplication? As computers do multiplication, there should be ways to perform binary multiplication in simple manner, right?

Edit: So, I mean like $11 \times 10$, $111 \times 100$ etc.

Comment: $0\cdot0=1\cdot 0=0\cdot 1=0$ and $1\cdot 1=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen OP actually meant (natural? integer?) numbers in base-2 representation ;)

Comment: The procedures you learned in Elementary school work nicely in binary, only simpler. As has been pointed out by Hagen von Eitzen, the multiplication table is much simpler.

Comment: Example: $11 \times 11 = 10 \times 11 + 1 \times 11 = 110+11 = 1001$, and indeed $3\times 3 = 9$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up long multiplication just like you learned in base $10$.  Say we want to multiply $1101_2 \times 101_2 = 13 \times 5 = 65$.  We can just do:$$\begin {align} 1101& \\ \underline{\ \ \  101}& \\ 1101& \\ 0\ \ & \\\underline{ 1101\ \ \ \ }& \\ 1000001\end{align}$$

Both the partial products (just copy) and the final addition are rather easier than in base $10$

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends quite a bit on what you mean by *simplify*.  As people have noted in comments, the same tabular scheme you used in school works well in binary, except that none of the single-digit-by-long-number multiplications actually have to be performed because the products are trivial; either they're the full number (suitably shifted) or zero (in which case they can obviously be ignored).  In fact, there's a version of binary multiplication using decimal versions that goes by numerous names but is perhaps best known as *Russian Peasant Multiplication*; see [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101093529/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.peasant.html) for the details on how it works, but it essentially repeatedly halves one number and doubles the other, then adds.

On the other hand, these methods - just like standard base-10 multiplication - still take $O(n^2)$ single-digit operations to multiply two $n$-digit numbers together.  In that sense, while the operations are being made simpler (at the cost of there being more of them - $n$-digit numbers in decimal correspond roughly to $3n$-digit numbers in binary), the *order* of growth still goes up quadratically as the number of digits gets bigger; if it takes 10 milliseconds to multiply thousand-digit numbers, it will take roughly 40 milliseconds to multiply two-thousand-digit numbers.  In this sense, the binary methods aren't really simpler at all.

So *are* there faster methods?  There are, but they're much more complicated.  The simplest(!) of the bunch works by noting that $(aX+b)(cX+d) = acX^2+(ad+bc)X+bd$; this looks like it takes four multiplications, but in fact the computation can be done with just three, since $ad+bc = (a+b)(c+d)-ac-bd$, and we've already computed the last two products.  If we're multiplying $2n$-digit numbers, then we can take $X=2^n$, break our numbers in half in the middle, and note (since the additions come almost 'for free' by comparison) that multiplying $2n$-digit numbers takes roughly $3$ times as long as multiplying $n$-digit numbers with this method; by applying the same algorithm recursively we get a method that takes roughly $3^k$ operations to multiply numbers of length $2^k$ (as opposed to the $\left(2^k\right)^2=4^k$ that the naive method uses), or in other words $n^{\log_23} \approx n^{1.6}$ operations to multiply numbers of length $n$.  This method has a fair bit of overhead, though - several more additions have to be done - so it's only a practical alternative for multiplying numbers that are hundreds or thousands of digits long.  (For more details, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm )

There are other methods that can improve this idea even further, all the way down to $O(n\log n\log \log n)$ time - in other words, *very* close to linear growth.  But whether it's actually possible to multiply numbers in linear time (on a 'standard' machine model) is actually an open question, so right now it's fair to say that *no one* knows how fast we can actually multiply!